Pymongo operation not responding intermittently
When I am trying to perform some mongodb operations using python program, the program will hang and doesn't respond. This issue occurs intermittently. If I retry once the issue occurred, the next operation may be successfully executed. This issue occurs even with the ping command. I am using python3.10, pymongo 3.10.0 and mongodb server 4.2.
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db_obj = client["my_database_name"]
query = {"name":"ABC"}

print("Going to perform mongo operations")
ping = client.admin.command('ping')
if ping['ok'] == 1:
   print("mongo is up and running")
   data = list(db_obj["collection_name"].find(query))
   print(data)
else:
   print("mongo is not up and running")

When the above code is executed, up to the first print statement  Going to perform mongo operations is getting printed when the issue is occurring. Then the application becomes unresponsive.

It's not intermittent if the issue occurs every time. Does it ever print either of the two statements? If not, then it means the connection isn't getting established. The ping command in your code is the first time a connection will actually be made to MongoDB. Btw, PyMongo 3.10.0 was released in Dec 2019. You can upgrade and use PyMongo 4.7, it supports MongoDB 4.2

If your MongoDB database server is up and running your code should work fine, as expected.

@aneroid The issue is not occurring always, but sometimes. The print statement mongo is up and running is getting printed. But when it become unresponsive, only the first print statement “going to perform mongo operation “ gets printed.

@prasad_  The mongodb server is up and running and everything is normal in logs as well. But The code is getting hanged at the line list(db_obj["collection_name"].find(query)) is what we observed while debugging

Have you tried running the same query from MongoDB shell or Compass tools and see what is happening? I had tried your code with an existing database and collection and the query printed an existing document.

Yes I have, but we didn't got any issues. This program is being running as a falcon application using gunicorn server and is deployed using k3s in aws. Both mongo and application is deployed in the same network . The same setup is working fine in azure. We are only facing this intermittent issue in aws.
